# App Store Connect issue ITMS-90129 keeps blocking upload

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

App Store Connect keeps blocking App upload by issuing

```
ITMS-90129: The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken.
```

So far I tried:

- Changing the Display Name, Bundle Identifier (even with generated Hashcodes to make sure that the names really are not taken already)
- Created alternative Profiles, Identifier and App in App Store Connect (also using the same mentioned hashcode)
- Tried these changes in the Xcode input fields (under 'General') and also directly modifiyng the Info.Plist
- Re-Exporting the project from Unity to XCode with the new naming (to make sure Unity is not writing some bundle id somewhere which is not visible in XCode)
- (Update) Tried to Clean the build folder based on
  [minchaej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12301279/minchaej) suggestion

Additional information: The XCode project is exported from Unity and we're using Firebase which is installed via Pods.

I'm grateful for any hint where to continue looking - because I'm really running out of ideas. Thanks a lot for taking the time.
Cheers
vik

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project before archiving? The changes might not be reflected.

Clean the Build: `Menu Bar → Product → Clean`
Clean the Build Folder: `Menu Bar → Product → Hold Option Key → Clean build Folder`
Delete Xcode Preferences: Run in terminal, `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I tried that but it didn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this (probably very Unity-to-XCode specific) issue was localization related:

I had to remove all but the English localization entry in the Localization section.

I'm not sure why there were other loca resources before (since we didn't set them up) but I assume these included an alternative app name which was causing the ITMS-90129 to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode version: 15.0.1.

I changed to both `Bundle name` and `Bundle display name` in Info.plist as the same as `Display Name` in Target -> General

Answer (score 0):

My salvation for ITMS-90129 is the next:

1. Remove definitions for

   `CFBundleName`

   `CFBundleDisplayName`

   `CFBundleSpokenName`

for base(en) localisation `InfoPlist.strings`.

2. Setup this variables with single value `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` directly in `Info.plist`
3. Variable `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` define via root project `Build Settings/Packaging/Product Name`
4. Setup variable `LSHasLocalizedDisplayName` in `YES` value in `Info.plist`
5. Setup Russian (or other) localisation for variables

   `CFBundleName`

   `CFBundleDisplayName`

   `CFBundleSpokenName`

via `InfoPlist.strings`

As I am personally assume, setup this variables via base localisation is the key of problems in which I am faced with

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was using a very generic name in the Player Settings (“Cards”), and just changed this for something a bit more specific (the app name they let me register on App Store Connect). This seemed to work.

[image: Player Settings]